# Shared Array not shared correctly in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am experimenting multiprocessing in Python and tried to share an Array of strings among two processes. Here is my python code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Value
import ctypes

def f1(a, v):
    for i, l in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
        a[i] = l*3

    v.value += 1

    print "f1 : ", a[:], v.value

def f2(a,v):

    v.value += 1

    print "f2 : ", a[:], v.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    val = Value(ctypes.c_int, 0)
    arr = Array(ctypes.c_char_p, 3)

    print "Before :", arr[:], val.value

    p = Process(target=f1, args=(arr, val))
    p2 = Process(target=f2, args=(arr, val))

    p.start()
    p2.start()

    p.join()
    p2.join()

    print "After : ", arr[:], val.value
```

When I run the script I see that `arr` is correctly populated and available in `f1()` but not in `f2()`. Here is the result:

```
    % python /tmp/tests.py
    Before : [None, None, None] 0
    f1 :  ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] 1
    f2 :  ['\x01', '\x11', '\x01'] 2
    After :  ['\x01', '\x01', '\x01'] 2
```

Did I overlooked something ?

Thanks in advance for your feedback. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is:

> `arr` stores 3 pointers. `f1()` assigns them to memory addresses that have no
>   meaning outside current process. `f2()` tries to access the
>   meaningless addresses that contain junk at this point.

Assigning to values that have meaning in all processes seems to help:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Value

values = [(s*4).encode('ascii') for s in 'abc']

def f1(a, v):
    for i, s in enumerate(values):
        a[i] = s

    v.value += 1

    print("f1 : ", a[:], v.value)

def f2(a,v):
    v.value += 1
    print("f2 : ", a[:], v.value)

def main():
    val = Value(ctypes.c_int, 0)
    arr = Array(ctypes.c_char_p, 3)

    print("Before :", arr[:], val.value)

    p = Process(target=f1, args=(arr, val))
    p2 = Process(target=f2, args=(arr, val))

    p.start()
    p2.start()

    p.join()
    p2.join()

    print("After : ", arr[:], val.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output

```
Before : [None, None, None] 0
f1 :  ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'] 1
f2 :  ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'] 2
After :  ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc'] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I can add more hints.
I've stripped the script to pinpoint the problem. It looks to me that the problem is in the `l * 3` operation. I don't know why, but moving the `l * 3` operation in the `enumerator` works as expected:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array                                   
import ctypes                                                                


def f1(a):                                                                   
#    for i, l in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):                                 
#        a[i] = (l * 3)                                                      
    for i, l in enumerate(['a' * 3, 'b' * 3, 'c' * 3]):                      
        a[i] = l                                                             

    print "f1 : ", map(id, a), a[:]                                          


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                   
    arr = Array(ctypes.c_char_p, 3)                                          

    print "Before :", map(id, arr), arr[:]                                   
    p = Process(target=f1, args=(arr, ))                                     
    p.start()                                                                
    p.join()                                                                 
    print "After : ", map(id, arr), arr[:]
```

Result:

```
Before : [3077673516L, 3077673516L, 3077673516L] [None, None, None]
f1 :  [3073497784L, 3073497784L, 3073497784L] ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
After :  [3073497784L, 3073497784L, 3073497784L] ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```